# how to connect a navigation bar (<nav>) with HTML files in google appscript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I am developing a code where I have different option levels and I want one of those options to display a nav bar with two tabs: one to search customers and the other to add customers, I already have the `loadView`, `loadCustomersView` and `loadAddCustomerView` function in my `clients.html` doc, but it does not display the content when I click on the tabs.
How can I make the navigation bar with the search and add clients options show me what is in `search.html` and `addcustomer.html`? (see image 3)

step 1, click in opcion1

[image]

step 2, click in opcion 1.1
[image]

step3, have a nav bar with 2 options: search and add customers
[image]

here is a copy of all my files.

codigo.gs

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function getOpcion1() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('opcion1').getContent();
  return html
}

function getObtenerClientes() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('clientes').getContent();
  return html
}



function loadPartialHTML_(partial) {
  const htmlServ = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(partial);
  return htmlServ.evaluate().getContent();
}


function loadSearchView() {

  return loadPartialHTML_("search");
}


function loadAddCustomersView() {

  return loadPartialHTML_("addcustomer");
}
```

Index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Gestor Virtual de Talento 1.0</title>


<style>
        .nav-link {
          cursor:pointer;
        }
        #loading {
          position:fixed;
          top:0;
          left:0;
          x-index:10000;
          width:100vw;
          height:100vh;
          background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  
  


<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-primary static-top mb-5" style="background-color: #072146;">
      <div class="container-fluid" style="height:67.33px; background-color: #072146">
          
             <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
             <a  class="badge badge-info" href="javascript:ventanaSecundaria('https://docs.google.com')" style="text-align: center;">Guía de usuario</a>
             </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    






<div class="container">
    <h3>Bienvenidos </h3>
    <h6>Selecciona una opción</h6>
    <P></P>
</div>





<div class="card-group">
  <div class="card">
    <div style="text-align: center;" >
    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&amp;id=1eBB_kiCc6FDkbDZwkKueZho-yDFeBOHU" alt="Card image cap" alt="" >
      <div class="card-body">
      <input type="button" value="Opcion 1" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #004481;color: #ffffff" 
                onclick="google.script.run
                .withSuccessHandler(actualizarDiv)
                .withUserObject(this)
                .getOpcion1()" />
      <P></P> 
      <p class="card-text">Conoce opcion 1</p>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&amp;id=1osgZRT_0ahKHXGyNbasbx_xaBr2_2orx" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
      <input type="button" value="Opcion 2" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #004481;color: #ffffff"
                onclick="google.script.run
                .withSuccessHandler(actualizarDiv)
                .withUserObject(this)
                .getOpcion2()" />
      <P></P>
      <p class="card-text">Conoce opcion 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&amp;id=1Hmxvyc9gM9KEpdQUalaNCvsPFJV8VYfJ" alt="Card image cap" >
      <div class="card-body">
      <input type="button" value="Opcion 3" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #004481;color: #ffffff"
                onclick="google.script.run
                .withSuccessHandler(actualizarDiv)
                .withUserObject(this)
                .getPagina3()" />
      <P></P>
      <p class="card-text">conoce pagina 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>






<p></p>
<p></p> 
<div id="resultado" class="container">
</div>





<P></P>








<script>
function ventanaSecundaria (URL){ 
               window.open(URL,"ventana1","width=1400,height=700,scrollbars=NO") 
              } 

function actualizarDiv(html, button) {
        var div = document.getElementById('resultado');
        div.innerHTML = html;
      }

</script>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

opcion1.html

```html
<P></P>


<br>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 g-4">



    <div class="col">
          <div class="card h-100" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=19CbMDqXEmgtPemrwiAlsaRyZmdMPrZqA" width="286px" height="180px">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Opcion 1.1</h5>
          <p class="card-text">conoce opcion 1.1</p>
          <input type="button" value="Accede aquí" class="btn btn-info" 
                onclick="google.script.run
                .withSuccessHandler(actualizarDiv)
                .withUserObject(this)
                .getObtenerClientes()" />

        </div>
      </div>
  </div>




  <div class="col">
<div class="card h-100" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=14_9fglXHnJhb4U4Xyy6XApBJ8KEerDd_" width="286px" height="180px">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Opcion 1.2</h5>
    <p class="card-text">conoce opcion 1.2</p>   
        <a  class="btn btn-info" href="javascript:ventanaSecundaria('https://google.com/')" style="text-align: center;">Accede aquí</a>
    
  </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

clientes.html

```html
<P></P>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
<div class="card mb-5" style="width: 18rem;">
<img src="http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&amp;id=13n5Nl3nZzL8GRJkG8EeNSPJi-vobrjw_" width="286px" height="180px" class="mx-auto">
<h5 class="text-center">Validación Clientes</h5>
</div>
</div>



<div class="container">
       <h6>Selecciona clientes y valídalos.</h6>
       <P></P>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <nav id="navigation" class="mb-3">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs main-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link active" id="search-link">Encontrar cliente</div>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <div class="nav-link" id="add-customer-link">Aniadir cliente</div>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
  <div id="app"></div>














    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<script>
  

function loadView(options){
  var id = typeof options.id === "undefined" ? "app" : options.id;
  var cb = typeof options.callback === "undefined" ? function(){} :  options.callback;  
  
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(html){
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html;
    typeof options.params === "undefined" ? cb() : cb(options.params);
  })[options.func]();
}

function loadSearchView(){
  loadView({func:"loadSearchView"});
}

function loadAddCustomerView(){
  loadView({func:"loadAddCustomersView"});  
}





document.getElementById("search-link").addEventListener("click",loadSearchView);
document.getElementById("add-customer-link").addEventListener("click",loadAddCustomerView);






</script>
```

search.html

```html
<h4>Search</h4>

<div class="mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchInput" placeholder="search...">
</div>

<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" class="text-right">#</th>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Nombre</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

addcustomer.html

```html
<h4>Add a Customer</h4>

<div class="add-customer-form">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="first-name" class="form-label">Nombre</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first-name">
  </div>
 <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="last-name" class="form-label">Apellido</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last-name">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="add-customer-button">Add Customer</button>
</div>
<div class="alert alert-success invisible mt-3" id="save-success-message" role="alert">
  New customer Added!
</div>
```

Comment: CAn you clarify what your question  is?

Comment: Create an [mcve] (don't forget to include the textual error messages from the web browser dev tools console / Google Apps Script executions page)